# How can I prevent the WordPress website from lagging when I scroll down with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, debugging

I made a WordPress website for a client 3 years ago using Spectrum Theme.
I checked the website yesterday and saw that there is a new behaviors that didn't exist before
When I scroll down with the mouse using the wheel the scroll are jumpy. I have an JS error saying
`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive`  
I tried to add `touch-action: none` to the CSS but nothing happened.
I also tried to add `window.addEventListener("touchstart", func, {passive: true} );`
But didn't know if I did it in the right place.
I also tried to edit jquery.mousewheel.js but nothing that I did change this.
How can I make it work smoothly again ?
this is the website
https://inwi-distribution.com/
You have to scroll with the mouse wheel to replicate the problem
thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] , then revise your post to provide more information. Links to elsewhere aren't adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `background-attachment: fixed;` to below mentioned DIV (it belongs to your homepage revolution slider code area) makes your website scroll very smooth:

```
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg " data-bgcolor="undefined" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url(&quot;https://inwi-distribution.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/IQ0A3143-1.jpg&quot;);background-size: cover;background-position: center top;width: 100%;height: 100%;opacity: 1;visibility: inherit;z-index: 20;background-attachment: fixed;" src="https://inwi-distribution.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/IQ0A3143-1.jpg"></div>
```

And also, you will have to play with CSS and get rid of `position: absolute;` for your images. Or at least reposition images a little bit that adds unwanted space above images.